# ASP.Net Web Forms URL routing same page with different URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

I am trying to make use of URL routing in my web forms application to make urls more user friendly. I would like to use the following mapping for one of my pages:

```
/services --> common/services.aspx
/services/seo --> common/services.aspx#seo
/services/hosting --> common/services.aspx#web-hosting
```

Can anyone please help me write the correct routing for this scenario? I would basically want to redirect the user to the different sections on the same page with different URLs as listed above.

Some of the URLs which are already working are:

```
//About Us
routes.MapPageRoute("", "about", "~/common/about.aspx", false);

//Contact Us
routes.MapPageRoute("", "contact", "~/common/contact.aspx", false);
```

Only the first one of the following works-

```
//Services - works
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/{service}", "~/common/services.aspx", false);

//does not work
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/web-development", "~/common/services.aspx#web", false);
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/seo", "~/common/services.aspx#seo", false);
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/digital-marketing", "~/common/services.aspx#marketing", false);
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @RahulSingh I have used the following routes, but only the first one works, others throw 404 error `routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/web-development", "~/common/services.aspx#web", false);
            routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/seo", "~/common/services.aspx#seo", false);
            routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/digital-marketing", "~/common/services.aspx#marketing", false);`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing similar problem, here's what i did finally. I set the routing of all Urls to the same page-

```
//Services
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services", "~/common/services.aspx", false);
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/web-development", "~/common/services.aspx", false);
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/seo", "~/common/services.aspx", false);
routes.MapPageRoute("", "services/digital-marketing", "~/common/services.aspx", false);
```

And moved the logic to jump to the section of the page to javascript (using jQuery):

```
$(function () {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("web-development") > 0) {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".service-web-development").offset().top }, 0);
            }
            else if (window.location.href.indexOf("seo") > 0) {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".service-seo").offset().top }, 0);
            }
            else if (window.location.href.indexOf("digital-marketing") > 0) {
                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".service-marketing").offset().top }, 0);
            }
        });
```

This checks the url of the page and moves the window location to the appropriate section of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an introduction to friendly urls: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Comment: I have already got some pieces of it working, the only thing i can't seem to figure out is using same url redirect the user to different sections of a page just like normal url request of www.abc.com#xyz

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers will prevent the server-side (ASP.NET) from reading anything after the # fragment for security reason. so you will not be able to communicate between pages unless on the client-side (JavaScript)...

Comment: The only thing i would use this hash(#) for is to let client display appropriate section of the page to the user just like if he sent this request www.abc.com#xyz (show the area where anchor has the name xyz). Is it not doable using friendly urls?